# how to show the message for session expired in asp.net using httpcontext

Tags: asp.net, session

Redirecting user to login page after session timeout is similar to refreshing the page after certain intervals method. Only thing which will differ is that calculating time after which the page has to be redirected. Hence time can be calculated using Session.timeout property which will give us session timeout value for that session. Add some grace timings to that value and redirect the user to the login page automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckSession();
    }

```
private void CheckSession()
{
    if (Session["SessionID"] == null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", "var r = confirm('Your Session Has Expired'); if (r == true) var str= 'PartnerLogin.aspx'; location.href = str ;", true);

    }

}
```